# React Native iOS App Crash with TextInput when multiline true

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

Below is the text input component in my React Native app. When users types more than 10 characters it hangs and crashes with below stack .  I have found the when  multiline is set false the crash goes away , but crashes when set true . This happens in iOS only and not Android . Crash stack here https://pastebin.com/A7Ufguhw

```
<TextInputComponent
        value={addressLine1}
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={(addressLine1) => {
          if (addressLine1 == '') {
            setaddressLine1(addressLine1);
          }
          if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(addressLine1)) {
            return;
          }
          if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9/,.-\s])+$/.test(addressLine1)) {
            setaddressLine1(addressLine1);
          }
        }}
        placeholder={'House no | Apartment name *'}
        inputStyle={[styles.addressFieldsText]}
        conatinerstyles={styles.addressFieldsTextContainer}
      />
```

which is a custom component

```
  <TextInput
    {...global.generateTestID('textInput-' + props.placeholder || props.label)}
    secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry || false}
    value={props.value}
    editable={props.editable}
    placeholder={props.placeholder ? props.placeholder : ''}
    style={[styles.textInputStyle, props.inputStyle]}
    multiline={props.multiline}
    numberOfLines={props.numberOfLines}
    placeholderTextColor={props.placeholderTextColor || theme.colors.placeholderTextColor}
    onFocus={props.onFocus}
    onBlur={props.onBlur}
    onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
    autoCorrect={props.autoCorrect}
    selectionColor={theme.colors.INPUT_CURSOR_COLOR}
    maxLength={props.maxLength}
    keyboardType={props.keyboardType}
    {...props.textInputprops}
    returnKeyType={props.keyboardType === 'numeric' ? 'done' : 'default'}
    autoCapitalize={props.autoCapitalize}
    autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
    selection={props.selection}
    onSubmitEditing={props.onSubmitEditing}
    selectTextOnFocus={props.selectTextOnFocus}
  />
```

What can be the reason behind this issue ?